# How to upload BigQuery Script to Github?

Tags: sql, github, google-bigquery

Need some help because the bigquery script does not save locally, and unable to upload it to Github.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: need to rephrase my question. I am not sure how to save my bigquery script to github. Is there a way, please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party IDE for BigQuery supporting GitHub
This is Goliath - part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).

[image]

***Note**: Another tool in this suite is Magnus - Workflow Automator. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc. Supports GitHub as a source control as well*

***Disclosure**: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team*